# get the redirected URL from the node.js

Tags: node.js, redirect, request

I have a url, which will automatically redirect to another URL , I use the following code to try the URL but seems doesn't work :

```
var request = require('request');

var url = 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Trackwork/TrackworkResult.aspx?Horseno=S001';


var r = request.get(url, function (err, res, body) {
  console.log(r.uri.href);
  console.log(res.request.uri.href);
  console.log(this.uri.href);
});
```

seems it shows the old URL but not the new ones.

What should I do to get the correct result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `request` library will automatically follow redirects with `30x` status codes. If you're getting the correct result, then it should be setting the `href` correctly. (See example below.) If the endpoint you're hitting doesn't do redirects in this way, you may need to pass [additional options](https://github.com/request/request#requestoptions-callback) like `followAllRedirects: true`.

```
const request = require('request');
const options = {
    uri: 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Trackwork/TrackworkResult.aspx?Horseno=S001',
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Mobile Safari/537.36'
    }
};
request(options, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(response.request.uri.href);
});
// Output: https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Trackwork/TrackworkOtherResult.aspx?HorseId=HK_2013_S001
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried and use the following code but seems not work : 
const request = require('request');
request({uri: 'https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/information/Chinese/Trackwork/TrackworkResult.aspx?Horseno=S001', followAllRedirects: true}, (error, response, body) => {
    console.log(response.request.uri.href);
});

Also, followOriginalHttpMethod: true seems not working too

Comment: It is not redirecting then. For proof, try `curl -L -v https://racing.hkjc.com/racing/informainese/Trackwork/TrackworkResult.aspx?Horseno=S001` (if on MacOS or Linux). The `-L` option tells curl to follow redirects. But it returns a 200 with no redirect.

Comment: yes, that's why it seems  very strange, you can redirect to another URL if you using a normal web browser. I pressed F12 and pasted the URL to see what's going on ...... it seems it returned status 302 and then redirect to the next URL , which is the ones I want .

Comment: Ok. That helps me understand what's going on. Try the above edit which uses a user agent string.

Comment: Yes, it works ! By the way, this is the Agent issue ? (I'm new to node.js just <10 days)

Comment: The user agent is text that lets a website know what type of client is asking for the web page. It's usually the browser name and type along with some operating system info.

Comment: @jcragun +1 for the answer. I wrote an answer, but didn't publish it because the redirect url was not reflecting for my `User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.103 Safari/537.36`.  Not sure why so. @philip888